# Sticky header not working with resizable column in Primeng.?

Tags: html, css, angular, primeng, primeng-datatable

I am trying to implement both [column resize](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/table/colresize) and [stick header](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/table/sticky). But sticky header works fine if I won't use the column resize. If I implement both, column resize is working but sticky header is not working.

I used the following css from primeng for the sticky header.

```
  :host ::ng-deep .ui-table .ui-table-thead > tr > th {
        position: -webkit-sticky;
        position: sticky;
        top: 70px;
    }

    @media screen and (max-width: 64em) {
        :host ::ng-deep .ui-table .ui-table-thead > tr > th {
            top: 100px;
        }
    }
```

and for the colum resize I used the below code, `[resizableColumns]="true"`,  `pResizableColumn`

```
  <p-table [columns]="cols" [value]="cars1" [resizableColumns]="true">
    ...
     <th *ngFor="let col of columns" pResizableColumn>
```

If I remove the `resizbleColumns` and `pResizableColumn` sticky header works fine. How can I make it works both things.? Here is the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-ls1xe1-mamqn3?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) and [Demo](https://github-ls1xe1-mamqn3.stackblitz.io/)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

when you set the p-table columns to be resizable the add a class `ui-table-resizable` this will reset some css property one of its the position of `th` to relative so you will lose sticky future

*this should fix the problem*

```
:host ::ng-deep .ui-table .ui-table-thead > tr > th {
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  background: blue;
  color: white;
  top: 0px;
  z-index: 1;
}

:host ::ng-deep .ui-table-resizable > .ui-table-wrapper {
  overflow-x: initial !important;
}

:host ::ng-deep .ui-table-resizable .ui-resizable-column {
  position: sticky !important;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 64em) {
  :host ::ng-deep .ui-table .ui-table-thead > tr > th {
    top: 0px;
  }
}
```

[**demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-ls1xe1-v15hjm)

**Updated!**

add the style in the component decorator is not reusable ,base of primeng theme recommendation of creating custom style we can do like this

*style.scss*

```css
.sticky-table {

      &.ui-table .ui-table-thead > tr > th {
        position: -webkit-sticky;
        position: sticky !important;
        background: blue;
        color: white;
        top: 0px;
        z-index: 1;
      }

     &.ui-table-resizable > .ui-table-wrapper {
        overflow-x: initial !important;
      }

      &.ui-table-resizable .ui-resizable-column {
        position: sticky !important;
      }

      @media screen and (max-width: 64em) {
        .ui-table .ui-table-thead > tr > th {
          top: 0px;
        }
      }
      
}
```

*template*

```html
<p-table styleClass="sticky-table" [columns]="cols" [value]="cars [resizableColumns]="true">
....
</p-table>
```

[**demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-ls1xe1-vakchg)

Answer (score 6):

Anyone who still might be interested:
For me it worked by just adding the following

```
:host ::ng-deep .p-datatable .p-datatable-wrapper {
    overflow-x: initial;
}
```

The Resizable-Fatures adds "overflow-x: auto" to the table, which hides the stick header.

Comment: It works for `autoLayout="true"`. Thanks.

Comment: It also works for  `responsiveLayout="scroll"`

Answer (score 1):

```
:host ::ng-deep .p-datatable .p-datatable-thead > tr > th {
        position: -webkit-sticky;
        position: sticky;
        background: blue;
        color: white;
        top: 0px;
        z-index: 1;
      }
      
      :host ::ng-deep .p-datatable-resizable > .p-datatable-wrapper {
        overflow-x: initial !important;
      }
      
      :host ::ng-deep .p-datatable-resizable .ui-resizable-column {
        position: sticky !important;
      }
      
      @media screen and (max-width: 64em) {
        :host ::ng-deep .p-datatable .p-datatable-thead > tr > th {
          top: 0px;
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use the below code:

```html
<p-table [columns]="cols" [value]="rows" [autoLayout]="true">
```

Comment: Explanation would be helpful :-)

Answer (score 0):

I had sticky Table Headers working without resize before. After adding resize it didn't stick anymore.

I fixed it on my small datatable (p-datatable-sm). I guess this works for normal size datatables with the right css class aswell.

> Angular v15.1, primeng 15.2

The Fix for me:

```
:host ::ng-deep .p-datatable-sm .p-resizable-column {
    position: sticky !important;
}
```

Explanation:

```
.p-datatable-resizable-table>.p-datatable-thead>tr>th.p-resizable-column:not(.p-frozen-column)
```

adds:

```
position:relative
```

and

```
:host ::ng-deep .p-datatable-sm .p-resizable-column {
    position: sticky !important;
}
```

overwrites that.